# IBM Cloud App ID: How to setup sign in for users using ibmcloud-appid?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I've been working in a project where I wanted to use IBM Cloud App ID to authenticate users. I'm able to sign-up new users using the [ibmcloud-appid node package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmcloud-appid). There are options to change email, change password, etc etc but I see no method for signing-in.

There are 2 ways to use this package - for securing APIs and for Web Applications. I wanted to use it to secure APIs. For web applications, they have their log-in page and users are able to log-in but for API, I could not find a way to send the user's email and password and authenticate them.

I've referred

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibmcloud-appid
https://github.com/rotembr/Cloud-Land/blob/master/backend/app.js
https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/06/custom-login-page-app-id-integration/
```

Everywhere they've used the IBM App ID's default log-in page. But I have my own login page and node end points. I need to send the email and password from the front-end to my node service and from node service I need to call the API to check if email, password is correct or not. How should I do this with ibmcloud-appid package ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend to take a look at this [IBM Cloud demo: Cloud Insurace Co](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/cloudco-insurance). It uses IBM Cloud App ID to authenticate users and has its [own login page](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/insurance-bot/blob/dev/public/login.html). The actual code is in the file [**app.js**](https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/insurance-bot/blob/dev/app.js). It uses the App ID **selfServiceManager** as well as Passport.

You would first need to obtain the authentication / JWT token and then later pass it in to the protected API endpoint.

Comment: Thank you data_henrik. 
After doing as you suggested, I get this error.

Error: Unknown authentication strategy "appid-webapp-strategy"
at attempt (/home/ztech/Videos/IBM AppID/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:186:37)
    at authenticate (/home/ztech/Videos/IBM AppID/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:362:7)

Comment: Check that you have "required" the modules. Look into the app.js how it is done.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look in https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/appid/relatedlinks.html#custom